# Dynamically change axes of a chart in power by using a slicer?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset in power bi in which I have two variables: time of entry and time of exit. The columns have a structure like this:

```
Time of entry  Time of exit
09:00          18:03
09:00          18:00 
09:00          18:00 
09:02          15:00 
09:05          15.02
```

The case is that I want to make a graph that shows me on the x-axis the hours of departure and on the y-axis the count that has had this particular hour. And the same with the entry time. Although it is possible to use two graphs (one with each subject) I would like the graph to change the axes dynamically using a slicer.

I have consulted some pages on youtube, and I am looking for the simplest possible way to do it, but I can't get it to work. I have tried configuring a parameter and DAX code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by using field parameters:

How to activate it:

[image: FRER]

Go to Modeling Tab --> New Parameter --> Fields

Then

[image: FRET]

Create a simple measure:

```
HourCount = 
COUNT(Timescale[Time of entry])
```

Then Create a line chart, put the created field parameter on the x_axis:

[image: FFFEidldöödf]

Resulting Screenshot:

[image: 1243]

[image: 5678]

Comment: Hi @Ozan Sen is this available in power bi desktop?

Comment: Yes! You need to activate it from options: I added a screenshot! I updated my solution above!

Comment: I can't see the option field in new parameter

Comment: Then you need to update your version! You are using an old version! This feature came in May-2022.

Comment: I don't get the option to import it in configuration and options either.

Comment: I told you! If you don't see it in the preview feautures on options, you need to download the latest version of Power BI Desktop; because It is old!